# Postfix: How to reconcile when A record points to outside IP, but hosts file points to 127.0.0.1

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix

**Environment:** Postfix 3.3, Node.js app, Digital Ocean Droplet

**Question:** I have a Node.js app that sends email through Postfix.  However when it attempts to send it throws a warning.

Warning message:

```
postfix/smtpd[4964]: warning: hostname server.example.com does not resolve to address 150.100.100.101
```

I believe I see the conflict in my `DNS Records` and `hosts` file.

DNS Records:

```
Type: A
Name: server.example.com
Value: 150.100.100.101

Type: MX
Name: example.com
Value: server.example.com
```

Hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 server.example.com server
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4
```

**Question:** If Digital Ocean assigns my server an IP address of 150.100.100.101 and Linux assigns my server an internal IP of 127.0.0.1 how do I reconcile this?

**Addendum:** I don't get this warning when I run the node.js app on my desktop and leave the mail server on Digital Ocean.  It only occurs when they are both running on the Digital Ocean Droplet which suggests the external DNS is somehow conflicting with the internal `hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the hosts file to reflect  the IP address to  150.100.100.101

Alternatively you can just comment out the line in the hosts file.